# comparison between two values in two tables and Append

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.x

I have two lists (normally they're much longer here is just an example) :

the first contain `Destination`, `mid`, `TypeSource`, `TypeDestination` and `Time`

```
[{'Destination': 'me.xx@domain.fr', 'mid': '6754', 'Type S': 'VOICE', 'Origine': '+45854521', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0', 'Time': '08:29:50.293'}, {'Destination': 'fax.server@domain.fr', 'mid': '6755', 'Type S': 'FAXG3', 'Origine': 'p0298220991', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0', 'Time': '08:55:33.731'}]
```

the  second list contain the mid and status to know whether a message is sent or not, sometimes there's an error and it sent after a repeat as you can see in the example

```
[{'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6754'}, {'status': 'Erreur', 'mid': '6755'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6755'}]
```

---

is there a way to make a test to see if the `mid` existing in `the first table` exists in the `second table`, if so `append the status` to `the first` by extracting it from the `second` ??

Comment: why not use dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> A = [{'Destination': 'me.xx@domain.fr', 'mid': '6754', 'Type S': 'VOICE', 'Origine': '+45854521', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0', 'Time': '08:29:50.293'}, {'Destination': 'fax.server@domain.fr', 'mid': '6755', 'Type S': 'FAXG3', 'Origine': 'p0298220991', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0', 'Time': '08:55:33.731'}]
>>> B = [{'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6754'}, {'status': 'Erreur', 'mid': '6755'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6756'}]
>>> mid_status = {}
>>> for d in B:
        mid_status.setdefault(d['mid'], []).append(d['status'])


>>> for d in A:
        if d['mid'] in mid_status:
            d['status'] = mid_status[d['mid']]


>>> A
[{'status': ['OK'], 'Destination': 'me.xx@domain.fr', 'mid': '6754', 'Type S': 'VOICE', 'Origine': '+45854521', 'Time': '08:29:50.293', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0'}, {'status': ['Erreur'], 'Destination': 'fax.server@domain.fr', 'mid': '6755', 'Type S': 'FAXG3', 'Origine': 'p0298220991', 'Time': '08:55:33.731', 'Type D': 'SMTP.0'}]
```

You may want a default value for status if you have none, in that case use:

```
for d in A:
    d['status'] = mid_status.get(d['mid'], [])
```

**Edit:** Updated as per request, to include support for multiple statuses

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there's a case where the status is error and then it's OK i've tried and it only insert when it's OK how can it insert both of them ?? ( i edited my question "2nd list" )

Comment: I've published another question to add another test

Comment: @KirkERW I had already updated this to do that test, try this code now it works